# Assertion failure on django project

Tags: python, django

I am new to python. I have created a Django project and I am running it locally.
My python project keeps runs fine until I run a function from my main.py file. The function runs fine but then python crashes:

`Assertion failed: (NSViewIsCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay() != currentlyBuildingLayerTree), function NSViewSetCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay, file /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1894.50.103/AppKit.subproj/NSView.m, line 13568.`

However I am unsure why this error is appearing. Anyone have experience in this type of error?

Comment: Are you using Matlib or Matplotlib?

Comment: i am using Matplotlib on my mac to produce a graph. do you think this is the problem?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286741/matplotlib-not-working-with-python-2-7-and-django-on-osx

Answer (score 1):

thank you, adding `plt.close()` to close off my plot stopped this problem.